# JavaScript [element].innerHTML = htmlcode is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a performance time delay in rendering `window.navigate(strURL);`. Until then I want display a wait message using `mainContainer.innerHTML = HTMLwait;` but it is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
var HTMLwait = "<div style='width:300px;height:300px;top:40%;left:45%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;display:inline;'><div style='width:50px;height:50px;top:20%;left:4%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;display:inline;'><img src='../../images/Developer/ajax-loader.gif'></div><div style='width:50px;height:50px;top:35%;left:0%;position:absolute;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;'>Loading...</div></div>";

var strURL = window.location.href;

var mainContainer = $(".mainContainer");
if (mainContainer != null) {
  mainContainer.innerHTML = HTMLwait;
}

window.navigate(strURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery objects use `.html()`,

```
$('.mainContainer').html(HTMLwait);
```

If you would like to use `.innerHTML` property:

```
document.querySelector('.mainContainer').innerHTML = HTMLwait;
```

```js
var HTMLwait = "<div style='width:300px;height:300px;top:40%;left:45%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;display:inline;'><div style='width:50px;height:50px;top:20%;left:4%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;display:inline;'><img src='../../images/Developer/ajax-loader.gif'></div><div style='width:50px;height:50px;top:35%;left:0%;position:absolute;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;'>Loading...</div></div>";


showMessage(HTMLwait);

function showMessage(message) {

  $('.mainContainer').html(HTMLwait);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('time to reload the page');
    // uncomment line below
    // window.location.reload();
  }, 1000); // executed after one second
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer"></div>
```

Comment: @user2082630 If you would like to delay reload - to let users see the message first, use `setTimeout` function. I've updated my answer, please see example how to implement reload. If it helped you, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`mainContainer` is a jQuery object and therefore does not have a `innerHTML` property. To set the HTML of an element selected via jQuery, use `html()`.

Note that a jQuery object will never be null. To check if it exists, use the `length` property. You should note though that checking that the element exists is redundant, as jQuery will not throw an error when calling a method on a jQuery object that holds no Elements.

Also you appear to be using `window.location.href` to reload the page. A much simpler method would be to just use `window.location.reload()`.

With all that said, try this:

```
var HTMLwait = "<div style='width:300px;height:300px;top:40%;left:45%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;display:inline;'><div style='width:50px;height:50px;top:20%;left:4%;position:absolute;overflow:auto;display:inline;'><img src='../../images/Developer/ajax-loader.gif'></div><div style='width:50px;height:50px;top:35%;left:0%;position:absolute;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;'>Loading...</div></div>";
var mainContainer = $(".mainContainer").html(HTMLwait);
window.location.reload();
```

Finally, there is a *lot* of inline styling in the HTML string you're appending to the DOM. You should really avoid inline styles. Instead place a class on the elements you append, then style them via an external stylesheet.

Comment: var strURL = window.location.href;  is used for getting the URL to redirect( not for reload) and this code does not work.Not showing the HTML wait message